# Incorrect syntax near '$'. when using list.contains

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I updated a solution from dotnet3.1 to dotnet8 and now, I'm having an issue with some queries. The solution uses EF and specifications. The problem appears every time `list.Contains` is used in the specification.

An example of a line causing the issue:

```
spec.AndCriteria(u => u.AppUserRoles.Any(ur => roles.Contains(ur.RoleId)));
```

Which is converted to:

```
DbSet<AppUser>()
   .Where(u => u.AppUserRoles
      .Any(ur => <>c__DisplayClass0_0.roles.Contains(ur.RoleId)))
```

And then transformed to:

```
DECLARE @__roles_0 nvarchar(4000) = N'[1,2,3,5,6,7,8]';

SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[AccessFailedCount], [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Email], [a].[EmailConfirmed], [a].[LastConnection], [a].[LockoutEnabled], [a].[LockoutEnd], [a].[MemberId], [a].[NormalizedEmail], [a].[NormalizedUserName], [a].[PasswordHash], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a].[SecurityStamp], [a].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a].[UserName]
FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [AspNetUserRoles] AS [a0]
    WHERE [a].[Id] = [a0].[UserId] AND [a0].[RoleId] IN (
        SELECT [r].[value]
        FROM OPENJSON(@__roles_0) WITH ([value] int '$') AS [r]
    ))
```

Obviously, this SQL query is incorrect. Run in MSSMS, you get the following message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near '$'.
```

Here is the error displayed in the app when requesting the user list page:

```
SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '$'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__209_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)
```

The way `roles.Contains` is transformed is wrong. `roles` is a list of id (integer)

Any ideas on why these queries are invalid now?

Packages:

- microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design\8.0.0\
- microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver\8.0.0\
- microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\8.0.0\

Comment: You might try the same in EF Core 7, as it may be a "bleeding edge" optimization bug.

Comment: Good chance it's just a bug - you can report it at https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/new/choose

Comment: Try the suggested duplicates. If they will not work for you I will reopen the question.

Comment: @StevePy it is optimization, but not a bug per se =) It is a breaking change in translation of `Contains` for SQL Server (see the duplicates) in EF Core 8.

Comment: @MartinCostello it can be considered a bug but more in application code though. See the duplicates.

Comment: it might be a bug, but more likely you're running old sql server or old compatibility level. OPENJSON with $ is perfectly fine in sql server 2016+ https://dbfiddle.uk/ZbLtq9mB Run `SELECT @@version` to see your version. `select cmptlevel from sysdatabases where name = DB_NAME()` should also return at least 130

Comment: Thank you all, I found an answer in one of the duplicates suggested: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/breaking-changes#contains-in-linq-queries-may-stop-working-on-older-sql-server-versions